# Web Security practical testing resources

Tags: asp.net, security

I have some basic knowledge about web security that I have gained through years of experience. Now I am interested in extending my knowledge and gaining a deeper understanding on how the exploit of common vulnerabilities (XSS, SQL Injection, etc.) is accomplished.

Can any of you point out some resources that...

- Explain technically the most common vulnerabilities in web sites
- Explain some less frequent (or less noticed) but possible vulnerabilities
- Give you a vulnerable test site and guide you (preferably step-by-tep) through the process of exploiting its vulnerabilities

If possible, I would like these resources to be focused on ASP.NET WebForms and MVC.

**Note:** I don't need to test a specific application, I want resources that allow me to better understand how this security flaws are created in web sites and how they are exploited by malicious users.

**EDIT:**

I also found [this great resource](http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/) on Google Code University that explains everything in a really understandable, cheesy, way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read following series:

- [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-1.html)

(and it ends with free ebook).

Answer (score 0):

you have a demo site:WebGoat, (for download)
and also you can use the site: 'Hack this site'.
they also may have video answers for the exercises.